# How to declare and fill a two dimensional array with a function vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

I have an array that is declared within a subroutine. I want it filled with two values. one for each coordinate of a list of cells. I know that this isn't always the best way to do this, but for reasons involving the rest of my program, I need to do it exactly this way.

```
'This sub contains more, I've just included only the relevant stuff
    Sub Start_Click()
        Dim arTime() As Integer
        arTime = FillTimeArray(arTime)
    End Sub


'This is used to fill the array with a list of 12 columns that are 24 rows long
'They are offsetted intentionally

    Function FillSpotArray(ByRef arr() As Integer) As Integer()
        For j = 0 To 11
            For i = 0 To 23
                arr(i, j) = Format(i + 2, j + 1)
            Next i
        Next j
    End Function
```

Comment: Your function is named `FillSpotArray` but in your test Sub you are calling `FillTimeArray`...

Comment: *I want it filled with two values. one for each coordinate of a list of cells* Does that mean that there are exactly 2 values, or are there 2 values for each coordinate? Also `Format(i + 2, j + 1)` only can be wrong => `Format(0 + 2, 0 + 1) = Format(2, 1)` and `1` is not a valid formatting... please make sure you know what [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) is doing. (You may be looking for `Array(i + 2, j + 1)`... )

Answer (score 0):

You have not dimensioned your array:

```
Sub Start_Click()
    Dim arTime(23, 11) As Integer
    arTime = FillTimeArray(arTime)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Dim you array, call the function correctly, and return the output correctly in the function

```
Sub Start_Click()
    Dim arTime As Variant
    arTime = FillSpotArray()
End Sub


'This is used to fill the array with a list of 12 columns that are 24 rows long
'They are offsetted intentionally

Function FillSpotArray() As Integer()
    Dim arr(23, 11) As Integer
    For j = 0 To 11
        For i = 0 To 23
            arr(i, j) = Format(i + 2, j + 1)
        Next i
    Next j
    FillSpotArray = arr
End Function
```

I'm not entirely sure of your use of `Format` here though